# As we set variable started = False, what is "if started:" means?

Tags: python-3.x, boolean-logic

I am really new to programming. This is a code that I don't understand, It would be great anybody could explain the logic behind this.

```py
command = ""
started = False
while True:
    command = input("> ").upper()
    if command == "START":
        if started:
            print("Car is already started")
        else:
            started = True
            print("Car Started")
```

In this code, I have doubt on how does the Boolean works. What does that line `if started:` means?

Comment: It's in a loop.  `started` will be `False` on the first iteration of the loop, so you'll go to the `else:`, but this then sets `started = True` so you will get `Car is already started` on subsequent iterations.

Comment: It will execute else Part first after that it will recall then it will call if condition (First you will get Car Started) after recall you will get (car is already started)